# Block accessing data by using /keystone/api/ URLs - KeystoneJs

Tags: keystonejs

I have created a keystoneJS application only for creating UIs. I don't need to create APIs. But it is allowing to access the data by using the URL `/keystone/api/`. How can I block this feature?

For Example I have created a model for storing site URLs as

```
var app = require('keystone');

var Sitemap = new app.List('Sitemap');

Sitemap.add({
  type:{
    type: String,
  },
  url: {
    type: app.Field.Types.Url
  }
});

Sitemap.defaultColumns = 'type, url';
Sitemap.register();
```

I did not create any route files or anything. But the JSON data is accessabe by calling the URL http://localhost:3000/keystone/api/sitemaps.

How can I disable this. Waiting for your valuable advises. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these APIs are only exposed if you are logged in as an admin. If you are not logged in as an admin, you shouldn't be able to get that information. Can you access this information if you aren't logged in as an admin?

Comment: Yes it is :) . Thanks for your replay